# How to send push notifications to Android device using Ionic?

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic an wanted to create an app to send push notifications. I want to start with ANdroid. These are the commands I have used to setup my project:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
ionic add ngCordova
ionic add ionic-service-core
ionic add ionic-platform-web-client
ionic add angular-websocket
```

Here is my app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic',
  'ngCordova',
  'ionic.service.core'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(['$ionicAppProvider', function($ionicAppProvider) {
  $ionicAppProvider.identify({
    app_id: 'xx',
    api_key: 'xx'
  });
}])

.controller('PushCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicUser) {

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:tokenReceived', function(event, data) {
    //alert("Successfully registered token " + data.token);
    alert('Ionic Push: Got token ', data.token, data.platform);
    $scope.token = data.token;
  });

  $scope.identifyUser = function() {
    var user = $ionicUser.get();
    if(!user.user_id) {
      // Set your user_id here, or generate a random one.
      user.user_id = $ionicUser.generateGUID();
    };

    // Metadata
    angular.extend(user, {
      name: 'Martijn',
    });

    // Identify your user with the Ionic User Service
    $ionicUser.identify(user).then(function(){
      $scope.identified = true;
      alert('Identified user ' + user.name + '\n ID ' + user.user_id);
    });
  };

  // Registers a device for push notifications
  $scope.pushRegister = function() {
    alert('Ionic Push: Registering user');
    var user = $ionicUser.get();
    alert("User Id:" + user.user_id);

    Ionic.io();
    var push = new Ionic.Push();

    var callback = function(data) {
      alert('Registered token:', data.token);
      //console.log(data.token);
      push.addTokenToUser(user);
      user.save();
    }
    push.register(callback); // ERROR
  };
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-websocket/angular-websocket.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <!-- Cordova is bootstrapped by ionic-platform-web-client, uncomment this if you remove ionic-platform-web-client... -->
<!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script></head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="PushCtrl">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <button class="button button-block button-dark" ng-click="identifyUser()">
          Identify a user
        </button>

        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-if="identified" ng-click="pushRegister()">
          Register for Push
        </button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

When running this code I can see the User in my Ionic dashboard. But when I hit the `Register for push` button, I get an exception: `ReferenceError: PushNotification is not defined` and then it points to `/lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.min.js:3:873`.

What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: `PushNotification is not defined` means that the Push plugin is not loading correctly. Are you running this in browser, emulator, or physical device?

Comment: I run this from the browser and also from my mobile device with Android on it

Comment: Push init and register should be done within `$ionicPlatform.ready()`. In browser, push works in development mode only.

Comment: So, I need to move `$scope.pushRegister` to the `$ionicPlatform.ready()`?

Comment: Yes, you need to wrap all code that interacts with plugins, including push register. Please let us know if it helps.

Comment: I still got the same error.I have the code into the `$ionicPlatform.ready()` function. When I browse (using Chrome) on my mobile device to my site, I do get the alert which says 'Identified user [...]'. But I don't get an alert with 'Token received'. When I go to the same page on my laptop (also using Chrome) I can see in the debugger the same error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushNotification` of undefined' in file `ngCordova.js line 5701`

Comment: What is the output of `ionic config info` command? Please do not include your real keys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93961/discussion-between-martijn-and-katemihalikova).

Comment: Try cordova push plugin .it is very easy to setup

Comment: @shammon OP wanted to use Ionic Push, which provides unifications between Android and iOS and integrates Ionic User service. Cordova push plugin is of course required as one of the steps in the tutorial, but is configured differently to plain Android notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to use new [tutorial](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-from-scratch), libraries you have installed are deprecated.
2. Notifications are not shown in development version, just callback is called.
3. When setting Android production push notifications up, you need to use GCM project number, not project ID or API key.